# ¿Es posible capturar un segfault con try/catch?

Tags: c++, try-catch

Para comprobar si es posible hice lo siguiente:

```
try
{
    int *x = 0;
    *x = 1234;
}
catch(...)
{
    cout << "OK";
}
```

Pero al ejecutarlo obtengo de igual manera un segfault. He leído en algunos sitios que try/catch no pueden capturar un segfault, pero no sé si sea cierto, podría alguien confirmarme eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En cualquier lenguaje, las excepciones no se generan de forma espontánea, sino que es el propio código el que se encarga de lanzarlas.

Así, por ejemplo, `new` lanza una excepción cuando no se puede realizar la reserva solicitada. Simplificando bastante, este sería un posible ejemplo de implementación de `new`:

```
int* new(unsigned int numElementos)
{
  int* ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*numElementos);
  if(ptr == nullptr)
    throw std::bad_alloc();

  return ptr;
}
```

En el caso del ejemplo que has puesto, el acceso a un puntero no inicializado no llama a ningún elemento de la librería estándar que pueda generar excepciones. Aquí entra en juego el Sistema Operativo. Los Sistemas Operativos modernos son capaces de monitorizar el acceso a memoria y lanzan errores cuando se intenta acceder a memoria para la cual no se tiene acceso. Debido a que la responsabilidad de provocar un fallo radica en el Sistema Operativo, la solución a aplicar para controlar estos accesos es dependiente del Sistema Operativo sobre el que va a correr la aplicación.

- Como norma general, en Windows este tipo de errores pueden capturarse usando `__try` y `__except`. Más información [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19(v=vs.80).aspx)
- En Linux el error se puede capturar escuchando la señal SIGSEV. Una posible solución en este caso, con la idea de gestionar excepciones, es capturar la señal y lanzar la correspondiente excepción:

Ejemplo Windows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <excpt.h>

int filter(unsigned int code, struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ep)
{
   if (code == EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
      return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;

   return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

int main()
{
   int* ptr = 0;

   __try
   {
     *ptr = 10;
   }
   __except(filter(GetExceptionCode(), GetExceptionInformation()))
   {
     std::cout << "Access Violation\n";
   }
}
```

Ejemplo de SIGSEV:

```
class SigSevException : public std::exception
{
public:
  SigSevException () noexcept
   : std::exception()
     m_what("Segmentation Fault")
  {}

  SigSevException (const SigSevException &) noexcept = default;

  SigSevException& operator= (const SigSevException &) noexcept = default;

  virtual ~SigSevException() = default;

  const char* what() const noexcept override
  {
    return m_what.c_str();
  }

private:

  std::string m_what;
};

void SignalSIGSEV(int signal)
{
  std::cerr << "señal SIGSEV lanzada";
  throw SigSevException();
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGSEGV , SignalHandler);

  try
  {
    int* ptr;
    *ptr = 85;
  }

  catch(const std::exception& exc)
  {
    std::cout << exc.what();
  }
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Entonces es imposible capturar un segfault en windows con C++ estándar?

Comment: Exactamente. Ni con C++, ni con C, ni con demasiados lenguajes como para enumerarlos

Comment: Lo ideal es prevenir este tipo de situaciones y para eso C++ te provee de bastantes mecanismos: constructores, iteradores, etc.

Comment: En otro foro un usuario compilo y ejecuto correctamente el código que postee con Visual C++, no dispongo de ese IDE si tu lo tienes podrías ver si funciona.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899749/i-get-a-segmentation-fault-instead-of-an-exception, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350489/how-to-catch-segmentation-fault-in-linux, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978234/catch-segmentation-fault-in-c. Puedes creerme a mí o puedes creer a esta gente que saben más que tu y yo juntos

Comment: Tienes razón ya he realizado la pregunta ahí http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144571/is-it-possible-to-catch-a-segfault-with-try-catch

Answer (score 3):

No, un fallo de segmentación es una señal, no una excepción. Las excepciones son lanzadas manualmente por el programa (bien tú, bien una librería), mientras que las señales son generadas por el sistema operativo ([`SIGSEGV`, `SIGABRT`, `SIGKILL`, etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals)).

Las excepciones se capturan con bloques `try`/`catch`, y las señales con [`signal handlers`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal).

Las señales no se pueden tratar como excepciones porque las excepciones se lanzan en una línea concreta del programa (donde ponga `throw`), mientras que las señales pueden aparecer en cualquier momento (dado que son como interrupciones, por ejemplo, que el usuario pulse Ctrl-C también genera una señal, `SIGINT`).

El manejo de excepciones implica añadir, por parte del compilador, cierto código de control en el ejecutable final para el *stack unwinding* (la destrucción de objetos locales a medida que la excepción atraviesa funciones) y la lógica `try`/`catch` (el fin del *stack unwinding*).

Para señales, ese código de control no se puede colocar alrededor de ninguna línea de código en particular porque las señales se reciben "por fuera", como si te tirasen una piedra en el tejado. Pueden ocurrir en cualquier momento.